# Acer Aspire V5-431 Webcam not working with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, webcam, acer

I have an Acer Aspire V5-431 with Ubuntu 14.04 (amd64) (before it has Windows 7 Home Basic x64), and everything works except the webcam. I searched the additional drivers but Ubuntu can't find it, I tried to update the kernel at the 3.16.1 but the problem continues.

What can I do?

Comment: have you installed guvcview

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't have to install driver software for things like cameras in Ubuntu and linux. Just install a camera app like cheese or guvcview. Open a terminal and type the following commands to install guvcview:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

The application will install as "GTK UVC video viewer".